# Replace characters from string with database value

Tags: php, mysql

I have string message `$message = 'Dear $firstname$ $lastname$, your point of city is $city$'`

I want to get value from Mysql data table for `$firstname$, $lastname$` and `$city$` and replace into message.

I have multiple user data selected from databases and New message stored into array.

```
$query = $ab->pquery("select firstname, lastname, city from tblaccount where country = $country";

$numOfrows = $db->num_rows($query);
for($i=0; $i<$numOfrows; $i++) {
    $toNumber = array();
    $toNumber['firstname'] = $db->query_result($result, $i, 'firstname');
    $toNumber['lastname'] = $db->query_result($result, $i, 'lastname');
    $toNumbers[] = $toNumber;
}
```

I want firstname, lastname and city replace dynamically for all user and store message into array.

How to Identify `$firstname$` replace with result of database filed `firstname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to let MySQL do the concatenation job, which will result in less PHP intsructions.

```
$messageSQL = "CONCAT('Dear ', firstname, ' ', lastname, ', your point of city is ', city)";

$query = $ab->pquery("select $messageSQL AS themessage from tblaccount where country = $country";

$numOfrows = $db->num_rows($query);
for($i=0; $i<$numOfrows; $i++) {
    $message =  $db->query_result($result, $i, 'themessage');
    $toNumbers[] = $message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            $query = $ab->pquery("select firstname, lastname, city from tblaccount where country = $country";

    $numOfrows = $db->num_rows($query);
    for($i=0; $i<$numOfrows; $i++) {
        $toNumber = array();
$message = 'Dear $firstname$ $lastname$, your point of city is $city$';

        $toNumber['firstname'] = $db->query_result($result, $i, 'firstname');
$message=str_replace('$firstname$',$toNumber['firstname'],$message); ///something like that
        $toNumber['lastname'] = $db->query_result($result, $i, 'lastname');
  $toNumber['message'] = $message;

        $toNumbers[] = $toNumber;
    }
```

Comment: Pawel You should include a description of what your code does in all your answers. I have seen that you are not including much more than the code in your answers and that may be fine on other pages but on SO all answers should have a description. Proper formating is also a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new array called `$messages` and store each of them in this array.

```
$query = $ab->pquery("select firstname, lastname, city from tblaccount where country = $country";

$messages = array();

$numOfrows = $db->num_rows($query);
for($i=0; $i<$numOfrows; $i++) {
    $firstname  = $db->query_result($result, $i, 'firstname');
    $lastname   = $db->query_result($result, $i, 'lastname');
    $city       = $db->query_result($result, $i, 'city');
    $messages[] = "Dear $firstname $lastname, your point of city is $city";
}
```